# R Memory allocation while reading large objects from Postgresql

Tags: r, postgresql, ram

I've noticed strange behavior in my R code. For simplicity, it is reduced to only a few rows. It has the following structure: I load libraries, establish the connection to PostgreSQL and then read the entire table in a variable from PostgreSQL. Afterward, I remove the variable with `rm()` and use `gc()`. If I check the memory usage (`mem_usage()` or `lineprof()`) the objects take less < 1GB in memory. If I run the code on Ubuntu 16.4 VM, I also can see with `htop`, `atop` the RAM allocated to my RSession. It is approximately 8 GB. The usage of `gc()` frees about 1 GB of RAM but does not improve the situation entirely. Only if I quite the Rsession such big RAM allocation is gone. I can run the code from Rstudio and from Terminal. The picture is the same. Here is a code snippet:

```
con <- establishDBConnection(databasename, hostname, portnumber,   username, passwortdb)
var <- dbGetQuery(con, paste0("SELECT * FROM ", myschema, ".", table, ";"))
rm(var)
gc()
```

I know that it is not a good practice to read the table at once.

I want to understand 1) why the object of size 1 GB allocations additional memory of 8 GB and 2) how to free the RAM without quieting the session.

Comment: What exactly is the question? How to force R to free the memory? It is impossible. The users do not have any control on memory deallocation.

Comment: @JRR Yes it was my question, but I want also to understand the reasons or logic of RAM allocation in R

Comment: I suggest you to read http://adv-r.had.co.nz/memory.html and more specifically this section http://adv-r.had.co.nz/memory.html#gc